# Critical points of quadratic forms

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, regression, mathematical-modeling

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ symmetric matrix, let $b$ be an $n$-vector, let $c \in \mathbb{R}$ and set $Q(x) = 1/2 x^T Ax-x^T b+c$. Prove that $x_0$, defined as a solution to $Ax_0=b$ is a critical point.

Additionally I am wondering what are the conditions on A such that $x_0$ is the minimizing point?  What happens in other cases?

Comment: Write down the necessary conditions for a critical point. Then check how much work is left to do.

Answer (score 1):

The critical points are defined as the points where the derivative becomes zero.  In this case, we calculate
$$
DQ = x^TA - b^T
$$
Alternatively, you can "complete the square" to find that
$$
Q(x) = \frac 12 (x - x_0)^TA(x - x_0) + c'
$$
for some vector $c'$.

We find that $x_0$ is a minimizing point when $A$ is positive definite, $x_0$ is a maximizing point when $A$ is negative definite.  Whenever $A$ is non-singular but falls into neither of the previous cases, $A$ will be a proper saddle point.  When $A$ is singular, $Ax_0 = b$ no longer has a unique solution (if such a solution exists).

Comment: Should've just left it at a comment about derivatives. Also perhaps give a hint as to why its a minimum if A is positive definite? As an aside, do you really need positive definiteness or is semidefiniteness enough?

Comment: @wonko you'll get **a** minimum when $A$ is semidefinite, but it won't be **the** minimum since we no longer have uniqueness.